# Mysql: group by two column from separated tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have posts and products. Posts is related with Products.

I need count all posts updated at current month (2017-07), but related product update date also is important.

Post3 is also updated this month, because have a product Product3.

If i try GROUP BY Posts.date_update, Products.date_update, but get incorect number.

```html
Posts
id | Name | date_update
1 | Post1 | 2017-07
2 | Post2 | 2017-08
3 | Post3 | 2017-08

Products
id | Name | date_update
1 | Product1 | 2017-07
2 | Product2 | 2017-08
3 | Product3 | 2017-07
4 | Product4 | 2017-09

PostsToProducts

id | post_id | product_id
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 3
3 | 1 | 4
4 | 2 | 4
5 | 3 | 2
6 | 3 | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have at least one Product related to an existing Post you could do something like :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Posts.Name)) FROM Posts, Products, PostsToProducts WHERE
Posts.id = PostsToProducts.post_id 
AND
Products.id = PostToProducts.product_id
AND
(Posts.date_update = '2017-07' OR Products.date_update = '2017-07');
```